# Input field, in table row, does not conform to std need to show error in next column of that row

Tags: jquery, tablerow

I hope what i want to do makes sense. I have the following form. The fields are in a table.

```
<form method="POST">
    <table class="FormFieldList" cellspacing="4">
        <tr>
            <td><span class="Required">*</span></td>
            <td><label for="FirstName">First Name</label></td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" inputChars="AN" inputReq="1" name="FirstName" inputMin="3" id="FirstName" size="40" maxlength="100" /></td>
            <td><span class="InputHelp">11</span></td>
            <td><span class="InputError">22</span></td>         
        </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

The fields need to conform to certain standards. This field has the following attribute which gets checked: inputMin="3". If the input length is less then I want to display an error in the 22.

My script looks like this and works great....sofar:

```
$(':input').blur(function(event) {  

if ($(this).attr("inputMin")!="")
{
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if ($(this).attr("inputMin")>$(this).val().length)
    {
        var Label=$('label[for="'+id+'"]').html();
        var Min=$(this).attr("inputMin");
        alert(Label+" needs a minimum of "+Min+" characters.")


        //NEED THIS HERE SO I CAN DISPLAY AN ERROR
        alert( $('table.FormFieldList td:last input[name='+id+']').val() )



        $(this).focus();
    };
};

});
```

Any sugestions?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you want to select the `span` that is in the last `td` of current row to display in it an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).closest('tr').find('td:last span')` will give you the `span` inside the last `td` of current row.

Comment: One mre question please. I removed the alert and place the warning message in the span as per your code. Works great but it goes into a loop and does not come out of it. Although I return focus to that input you would not expect that. Thanks again.